# Почему когда я вызываю функцию выскакивает ошибкаUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' ?of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
  let ccc = document.querySelectorAll('.css-4');
        for (i = 0; i < ccc.length; i++) {
    function aa() {
         ccc[i].setAttribute('title', 'test - data');
           };
       };
             aa();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let ccc = document.querySelectorAll('.css-4');

function setProps() {
  for (i = 0; i < ccc.length; i++) {
    ccc[i].setAttribute('title', 'test - data');
  };
};

setProps();
console.log(ccc);
```

```html
<div class="css-4"></div>
<div class="css-4"></div>
<div class="css-4"></div>
<div class="css-4"></div>
```

Comment: Мне именно нид присваивать атрибут при вызови функции

Comment: @user355360 так тогда уточняйте свой вопрос, минус зачем ставить ?

Comment: @user355360 отредактировал

Comment: я вроде бы не ставил его ))Так что сорри)